# How to generate Model/Example value section for GET request in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-php

I am concerned on generating Model/Example value section for my GET request with Swagger.
[The link](http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/findPetsByStatus) to official example shows that section perfectly.

In official docs it is generated using existing model:

```
     *     @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/User")
```

I don't have such an option, because my properties is generated by REST.

I have tried the following way:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Get(
...
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response="200",
 *         description="Ok",
 *         @SWG\Schema(
 *             type="array",
 *             @SWG\Property(property="firstname", type="string", example="Steven")
 *         ),
 *     ),
 * )
 */
```

It is not working and answers:

`fetching resource list: http://localhost/dist/swagger.json; Please wait.`

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `GET /pet/findByStatus` is generated in one of the examples:
[github.com/zircote/swagger-php/.../Examples/petstore.swagger.io/controllers/PetController.php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/petstore.swagger.io/controllers/PetController.php#L69)

The reason your snippet isn't working is because you're adding a property to an `array` type, which isn't supported.

To describe the contents of the array you'll need the `@SWG\Items` annotation:

```
...
 *         @SWG\Schema(
 *             type="array",
 *             @SWG\Items(
 *                 type="object",
 *                 @SWG\Property(property="firstname", type="string", example="Steven")
 *             )
 *         ),
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Succeeded w/o Items though, it needed just to change type from array to object.